# MySQL and JDBC Error Logging In

Tags: java, jdbc

I've been messing around with JDBC and trying to connect to a test database that I've created, however I keep getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I've tried two variations of my code both throwing back the same error here they are:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Connection connection = null;
       Statement statement = null;
       try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?   user=root&password=1234");
           System.out.print("Connected");
           connection.close();
           System.out.println("Closed");
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Error: " + e);
       }
   }
```

As well as:

```
public class JDBC {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "1234";
    System.setProperty(driver, "");

    try {
        DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on where to go on from here?

Comment: Message is pretty much descriptive, it seems either userID, password (or) combination of both are not matching.

Comment: When I was installing MySQL, it asked to give root a password which I set to "1234", no quotes obviously.

Comment: Try login using mysql workbench (or) sql editor and check login is working fine or not

Comment: Works fine from the work bench: http://i.imgur.com/nt6Bu.png

Comment: Port in screenshot showing as 3307, but in your program it is 3306, could that be causing issue?

Comment: That fixed it, I'm a derp. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped. Added as answer. If helped accept it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message is pretty much descriptive, it seems either userID, password (or) combination of both are not matching

EDIT:

After screenshot issue is related to wrong port definition in program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1. Reset password of root. Check your connection URL.
2. If #1 does not work then instead of using root, create new user with full access rights.